# fopen error when installing Composer for PHP (Windows 7)

Tags: php, composer-php

I am attempting to install Composer under Windows 7 Ultimate. Unfortunately, whenever I run a command, Composer generates an fopen() exception (see below).

My guess is that an empty filename is being passed somewhere, possibly as the result of a configuration error.

In testing I have I have deleted and reinstalled Composer, tested against two
versions of PHP and checked my GitHub connection / updated the interface.

An example of the error (it's the same whatever I do) is as follows:

? composer -vvv diagnose
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
 Disabling it when using Composer is recommended.
Checking git settings: Executing command (CWD): git config color.ui

[ErrorException]
  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty

Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:55
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a
 fopen() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:55
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\WindowsPipes->__construct() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Pipes/WindowsPipes.php:172
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\WindowsPipes::create() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:1264
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->getDescriptors() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->start() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:208
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:62
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/DiagnoseCommand.php:166
 Composer\Command\DiagnoseCommand->checkGit() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/DiagnoseCommand.php:82
 Composer\Command\DiagnoseCommand->execute() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:82
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:25

All assistance appreciated

Comment: Have you installed it and run as administrator?

Comment: I am a member of the Administrator's group.

Comment: Problem resolved: the sys_temp_dir entry [php.ini] was pointing to a missing directory ... <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved: the sys_temp_dir entry [php.ini] was pointing to a missing directory